# Can I assign multiple refs to the same Element/Node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-ref

I have a function component that forwards the incoming ref from the parent to a `div` that it is rendering. I also want to create a ref inside the component and assign it to the same `div`. But I can't since an element takes only one ref. Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround for an issue like this?

The `ref` coming from the parent is a `React.Ref`, but I need a `React.RefObject` to pass it to 3rd party hooks like react-use's `clickAway`: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useClickAway.md

Here is the example component:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

type Props = React.PropsWithoutRef<JSX.IntrinsicElements['div']>;

function Component({ ...props }: Props, ref: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>) {
  const wrapper = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      // ref={wrapper}
    />
  );
}

export default React.forwardRef(Component);
```

Comment: You don't have create two refs for the same dom node. You can easily use the forwarded ref in the child component and work as if you norrmally do with ref. In your case in `Component` component, just use `ref.current `.

Comment: I updated the question, added why I needed.

Answer (score 7):

### Short Answer

---

You can use a simple function like this to merge the refs

```js
const mergeRefs = (...refs) => {
  return node => {
    for (const ref of refs) {
      ref.current = node
    }
  }
}
```

### Why it works

---

The reason why this works is because, under the hood, the ref prop can accept a function with a self referencing node as the argument.

```js
import React from "react"

export default () => {
  const ref1 = React.useRef(null)
  const ref2 = React.useRef(null)
  return (
    <div
      ref={node => {
        ref1.current = node
        ref2.current = node
      }}
    >
      Hello
    </div>
  )
}
```

Credit for the examples goes to [this article](https://medium.com/@mayursinhsarvaiya/how-to-merge-refs-in-react-component-d5e4623b6924).

### useRef Typing

---

Typewise, it looks like this. Personally, it's not clear to me how to read `RefCallback` - it looks like a self referencing function with a generic argument T and somehow T represents the node itself. Open to someone further clarifying it.

```
interface RefObject<T> {
    readonly current: T | null;
}
type RefCallback<T> = { bivarianceHack(instance: T | null): void }["bivarianceHack"];
type Ref<T> = RefCallback<T> | RefObject<T> | null;
```

### Typescript Answer

---

If you want to add a few more checks and balances you can use this typescript compatible function taken from headlessui from Tailwind.

```
function useSyncRefs<TType>(
  ...refs: (
    | React.MutableRefObject<TType | null>
    | ((instance: TType) => void)
    | null
  )[]
) {
  let cache = React.useRef(refs);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    cache.current = refs;
  }, [refs]);

  return React.useCallback(
    (value: TType) => {
      for (let ref of cache.current) {
        if (ref == null) {
          console.log('ref is null');
          continue;
        }
        if (typeof ref === 'function') {
          console.log('ref is a function. Returning called function');
          ref(value)
        } else {
          console.log('returning the value: ', value);
          ref.current = value
        };
      }
    },
    [cache]
  );
};
```

You can see it in action in this [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@paulwongx/usesyncrefs).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you want to assign another ref to this div. Ref is just a reference to DOM. Wrapper ref and the ref from props is just the same.

*Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.*

In that case, if you want access this ref for div.

```
function Component({ ...props }: Props, ref: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>) {
  const wrapper = ref;

  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      // ref={wrapper}
    />
  );
}
```